# Install Fragaria framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I was looking for a way to implement syntax highlighting on my cocoa app and I found the great Fragaria framework https://github.com/mugginsoft/Fragaria. Unfortunately I seem to be unable to install the framework in my app.

Here are the steps I follow:

1. Compile the framework from the source code target
2. Add the framework to the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase of XCode 4
3. Drag the framework into "Copy Bundle Resources"of build phase

Unfortunately when I try to build my app I get this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/MGSFragaria.framework/Versions/A/MGSFragaria
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/dedalus/Developer/DEGS/trunk/build/Debug/DEGS.app/Contents/MacOS/DEGS
>   Reason: image not found

Which step am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the framework product to the *Copy Bundle Resources* build phase. Instead, create a new *Copy Files* build phase, set its destination to the *Frameworks* directory and add the framework build product to this phase. The *Copy Bundle Resources* build phase copies the framework to the resources subdirectory (`Contents/Resources` on OS X), but the dynamic linker expects it to be in the frameworks subdirectory (`Contents/Frameworks` on OS X). The newly added *Copy Files* build phase will put it there.

BTW, the error you're seeing is a run-time error, not a compile-time error. So strictly speaking you get this error when running the app, not when building it.